# Resolve equation in sens of D'

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

can you help me please, to find  $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$,solutions of the equation $xu=H+c $ where $c$ is an constant, $x$ the function identity, and $H$ is Heaviside function. I purpose this solution.

Let $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}).$
since $x \in C^\infty$,then $\psi=x \varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$. We have for all $x \neq 0$
\begin{align*}
<u,\psi> & = \displaystyle\int_0^\infty \varphi(x) dx + c \displaystyle\int_0^\infty \varphi(x) dx\\
&= \dfrac{1}{x} \displaystyle\int_0^\infty \psi(x) dx+ c  \dfrac{1}{x} \displaystyle\int_0^\infty \psi(x) dx
\end{align*}
Then, 
$u= \dfrac{1}{x}(1+c)$ sur $]0,+\infty[$.

But what about $x \in ]-\infty,0]$ in the case where my purpose is true?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you need to solve three different equations.

First we need to learn how to solve the equation $$xu=0.$$This is a standard result, the solution writes $u=b\delta_0$ with $b$ an arbitrary constant.

Second, the equation $$xu=1$$ has a particular solution $PV(1/x)$ - the principal value.

Finally, the most interesting one is the part $$xu=H.$$ The naive approach would be to say that $$s=\begin{cases}1/x,&x>0\\0,&x\le0.\end{cases}$$
This, however, *is not* a distribution on $\Bbb R$, hence we need to invent something else.

We can notice that the antiderivative of $s$, namely, $H(x)\ln x$, is a distribution (it is locally integrable) on $\Bbb R$, so we would like to say that $u=-(H(x)\ln x)'$. A quick integration by part shows that indeed in the sens of distributions one has
$$-x(H(x)\ln x)'=H(x).$$

We can now combine all these results into the final answer

$$u = -(H(x)\ln x)'+cPV(1/x)+b\delta_0,\quad b\in \Bbb C.$$